# Proving that $[0, 1]$ is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces, connectedness

I'm just learning about connectedness and want to show that the interval $[0, 1]$ is connected. However,
I'm very unsure whether my attempt is correct (doubt it).

**Attempt:**

Suppose there existed disjoint open sets $A, B \neq [0, 1], \varnothing $ s.t. $A \sqcup  B = [0, 1]$, meaning
$A, B$ are open as well as closed. Then one of the values $\sup_{}(A), \inf_{} (A), 
\sup_{}(B), \inf_{} (B) $ is not in $\{0, 1\}$, as one can quickly see. W.l.o.g. let this be
$i_{B} = \inf_{} (B)$. Since $B$ is closed, it must be that $i_{B} \in B$ and further there exists some
$\epsilon>0$ s.t. $(i_{B} - \epsilon, i_{B} + \epsilon)\subseteq B$, in particular $i_{B} - \epsilon / 2 \in B$,
which contradicts the choice of $i_{B}$.

Is this proof sound?

Comment: ah no there is a problem. You proved only what are the inf and sup of $B$ and not that $B$ is equal to $[0,1]$

Comment: @FedericoFallucca well I assumed that $A, B$ are not $\varnothing$ or $[0, 1]$ and showed that this leads to a contradiction

Comment: yeah but I don’t understand why you can say that values are not ${0,1}$

Comment: @FedericoFallucca well I say that one of them must be neither $0$ nor $1$, for if such a value didn't exist, it would mean that either the sets are not disjoint (since they all contain ther inf/sup), or that one of the sets is $\{1\}$ for example, which is not open however.

Comment: An alternative method without infimum and supremum would be to show $[0,1]$ is convex thus path-connected thus connected.

Comment: @zwim This would be circular. The proof that path-connected spaces are connected is based on the fact the $[0,1]$ is connected.

Comment: At your level, a "sound" proof should not include the phrase "as one can quickly see".  You should explain this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but perhaps a bit short concerning the fact $\exists x \in\{\inf(A),\sup(A),\inf(B),\sup(B)\}\colon x  \not\in \{0,1\}$. I think a more transparent approach is to prove that one of $\inf(A),\inf(B)$ must be contained in $(0,1)$. This can be done as follows:

1. We have $\inf(A) \in A$ and $\inf(B) \in B$ because $A,B$ are closed.
2. We must have $\inf(A) < 1$ and $\inf(B) < 1$. Otherwise one of $A, B$ would be the one-point set $\{1\}$ which is not open in $[0,1]$.
3. If $\inf(A) > 0$, we are done because $\inf(A) < 1$.
4. If $\inf(A) = 0$, it is impossible that $\inf(B) = 0$ because then $0 \in A \cap B$. Thus $\inf(B) > 0$ and we done again as in 3.

So you may assume w.l.o.g. that $\inf(A) \in (0,1)$ and continue as in your qusetion.

**Update:**

Here is an even shorter proof.

1. We have $\inf(A) \in A$ and $\inf(B) \in B$ because $A,B$ are closed.
2. We must have $\inf(A) = 0$: Suppose that $\inf(A) > 0$. Then, because $A$ is open in $[0,1]$ and $\inf(A) \in A$, there exists an element of $A$ which is smaller than $\inf(A)$. This is a contradiction.
3. Similarly we must have $\inf(B) = 0$.
4. We get $0 \in A \cap B$, a contradiction.

Comment: thanks for the clarification!